# Office.js Word API not able to read plain text type content controls

Tags: office-js

I am trying to get all content controls present in the document. As per microsoft Word API docuemntation only RichText and plain Text type content controls are supported. But i am not able to get the plain text type content controls. I get only richtext content controls.

```
const contentControls = doc.contentControls;
  contentControls.load('title, tag, type'); 
  return context.sync().then(function () {
    // Loop through the content controls
    console.log(contentControls.items.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < contentControls.items.length; i++) {
      const contentControl = contentControls.items[i];
      console.log(`Content Control #${i + 1}`);
      console.log('Title: ', contentControl.title);
      console.log('Tag: ', contentControl.tag);
      console.log('Type: ', contentControl.type);
    }
  });
```

I tried using below WordAPI refrence:
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js
OR
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js
With both refrences the result contains only richtext content controls.

Am i missing something or plain text type content controls are still not supported via word API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain text content controls are currently supported in [Word JavaScript API requirement set 1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-1-5-requirement-set?view=word-js-preview). Please use [Document.getContentControls(options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-getcontentcontrols-member(1)) API. Leaving the `options` parameter empty will get both rich text and plain text content controls in the document. If you want plain text only, please specify the option "PlainText".